# Bridge between simulated network and real host

Tags: linux, networking, tap, ns-3

I need to build a bridge (tap) between a simulated network (NS-3) and the real Linux host So when the "bridged" node receive a packet in NS-3, the real Linux host receive the packet. 
How i can build such bridge? Could you give example? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.10/doxygen/group___tap_bridge_model.html

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use linux bridge. Create a bridge and add the physical host interface & logical interface (tap) in the same bridge.